# Connect USB to VirtualBox

Tags: 16.04, usb, virtualbox

I tried every solution I find here or in other forums to connect usb to vbox.
First of all, i installed vbox addition then, I tried to add the user to `pvboxusers`, `install dkms`, `gnome-system-tools`, `virtualbox-dkms` unfortennly i still cannot connect my USB device to the VM on Vbox.
When I try to do that, I got 
I'm working on UBUNTU 16.04.1 LTS Gnome (xenial)
Virtualbox Version 5.1.14 r112924 (Qt5.5.1)

[image: when i try to add USB device i got <no devices available>]

Comment: what does lspci -v show in a command line?

Comment: [lspci -v result](http://textuploader.com/dt1v3)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/683742/virtualbox-not-seeing-usb-devices-even-though-i-am-in-vboxusers-group?rq=1

Comment: my vbox doesn't accept this version of pkg

Comment: The you need to wither update the version or download and install the extension pack of the same version.

Comment: it's not about extensions  I installed it but <no devices available>

Comment: You also need to add your user to the `vboxusers` group as stated in the link I posted in the beginning and that you didn't read.

Comment: i mentioned that i did all this instruction